# server dont receive data from client

Tags: c, windows, udp, client-server, ipv6

My server doesn't receive any data from the client, but there are no errors so I really don't know what's wrong. In the while loop on the client I try to send a message. The server stays in the recvfrom function and seems to get not data. A netstat in the cmd shows that server listens to the Port 50000. I give the IPv6 address ::1 with a console argument to the client.

Here's the code for the server:

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <ws2ipdef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PORT 50000

#define BUFFERSIZE 64

void error(char *err)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"%s: %d\n", err, WSAGetLastError());
    getchar();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
struct sockaddr_in6 server, client;
SOCKET sock;
char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
LPTSTR recvBuff[1024];
DWORD recvBuffLen = 1024UL;
int len = sizeof(client);

WORD wVersionRequested;
WSADATA wsaData;
wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(1,1);
WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);

sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (sock < 0)
    error("Fehler beim Anlegen des Sockets");

memset( &server, 0, sizeof (server));
memset( &client, 0, sizeof (client));

server.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
server.sin6_port = htons(PORT);
server.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;

if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) == -1)
    error("Fehler beim binden des Sockets");

while (1)
{
    if (recvfrom(sock, buffer, BUFFERSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &len) == -1)
        error("Fehler beim erhalten von Daten");
    printf("...");
    printf("Pakete erhalten von: %s:%d\nDaten: %s\n\n", WSAAddressToString((struct sockaddr *)&client.sin6_addr, len, NULL, *recvBuff, &recvBuffLen), PORT, buffer);
}

closesocket(sock);
return 0;
}
```

And here the code for my client:

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <ws2ipdef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PORT 50000

#define BUFFERSIZE 64

void error(char *err)
{
fprintf(stderr,"%s: %d\n", err, WSAGetLastError());
getchar();
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
struct sockaddr_in6 server;
SOCKET sock;
char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
int len = sizeof(server);

WORD wVersionRequested;
WSADATA wsaData;
wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(1,1);
WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);

if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s <Server-IP>\n", argv[0]);
    getchar();
    exit(0);
}

sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (sock == -1)
    error("Socket Fehler");

memset( &server, 0, sizeof (server));

server.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
server.sin6_port = htons(PORT);
if ((WSAStringToAddressA(argv[1], AF_INET6, NULL, (SOCKADDR *)&server, &len)) < 0)
    error("String konnte nicht aufgelößt werden");

while (1)
{
    printf("\nDaten eingeben: (Enter für Text bestätigen, 'q' eingeben um zu beenden)");
    scanf("%[^\n]", buffer);
    getchar();
    if (strcmp(buffer, "q") == 0)
        exit(0);

    if (sendto(sock, buffer, BUFFERSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, len) == -1)
        error("Fehler bei Übertragung");
}

closesocket(sock);
return 0;
}
```

I hope someone can help.

Comment: humm have you turned off your firewall? :-)

Comment: sendto returns 64 and the firewall is off

Comment: have you tried using the normal ipv4 and have you checked the error code (if any)? have you tried using setsockopt (SO_REUSEADDR)

Comment: i cant use IPv4 because my task is to use IPv6

Comment: Can you check with WireShark to see if the packets are arriving at the destination ok?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: the problem might be `stdout` buffering - try disabling it with

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

or just flush `stdout` after your `printf()`:

```
printf("...");
printf("Pakete erhalten von: %s:%d\nDaten: %s\n\n", WSAAddressToString((struct sockaddr *)&client.sin6_addr, len, NULL, *recvBuff, &recvBuffLen), PORT, buffer);
fflush(stdout);
```